# Searching a lot of text files for a specific text written in textbox and display them

Tags: c#, .net, performance, search

I am trying to search many text files from a particular directory and then textchanged event to find text in all files and display on screen only lines which contain that text.

Currently it is working but it is too slow. I am posting a function which searches text and display in listbox. what could be most efficient way to make it work little speedy.

```
listBox2.Items.Clear();
ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();

if (txtfile.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < txtfile.Count; i++)
    {
        lines.AddRange((File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(path, txtfile[i].ToString()))));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        if(lines[i].ToString().IndexOf(txt,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)>=0)

        {
                listBox2.Items.Add(lines[i].ToString());
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `txt`, what is `txtfile`?

Comment: With the `TextChanged` event, with every change in text in the `Textbox`, the search will refire, which will lead to slower performance. Perhaps trigger the search based on a `Button_Click` rather that the `TextChanged` event, which will fire for every character added or removed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter txt is text which is to be searched and txtfile is array which contains all files to be searched

Answer (score 2):

How many files are you searching? You could always index them , store the contents in a SQL database, and of course use Parallel.For

```
Parallel.For(1, 1000, i =>
    {
        //do something here.
    }
);
```

Comment: This link might also be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and `File.ReadLines` since they are less memory hungry:

```
var matchingLines = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, ".txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .SelectMany(fn => File.ReadLines(fn))
    .Where(l => l.IndexOf(txt, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
foreach (var line in matchingLines)
    listBox2.Items.Add(line);
```

I would also search only when the user triggers it explicitely, so on button-click and not on text-changed.